# Error en un código cuando se generalizan los datos

Tags: java, poo, lista, pilas

Tengo una pregunta sobre el siguiente código, la idea es que si se le da como input:

> `a + b + c + d + ... + z`

Da como salida:

> expresion correcta

Si se le da como input:

> `a + b + c ++ b + b b...z`

Da como salida:

> expresion incorrecta

El programa trabaja bien si se le da:

> `a+b`

Pero hay un error cuando le introduzco

> `a+b+c+d`

Pues me da como output:

> expresión incorrecta

Cuando es correcta.

```
public class Ejercicio5sep {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList pila = new LinkedList();
    int correcto = 0;

    System.out.println("Cuantos elementos quiere introducirle a la pila?");
    int n = x.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("introduzca su elemento");
        String e = x.next();
        pila.push(e);
    }
    if (pila.size() % 2 != 0) {

        float d = (float) pila.size() / 2f + 0.5f;

        for (int i = 0; i < pila.size() / 2; i++) {
            String a = (String) pila.pop();
            String b = (String) pila.pop();

            if (false == a.equals("+") && b.equals("+")) {
                correcto++;
            }
        }

        String c = (String) pila.pop();

        if (false == c.equals("+"))//(*)
        {
            correcto++;
        }
        //si input: a+b+c+d
        System.out.println(correcto);//dice que correcto==2, entonces 
        //no hizo la instruccion (*), ?porque

        if (correcto == d) {
            System.out.println("La expresion es correta");
        } else {
            System.out.println("La expresion no es correta");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("expresion incorrecta :(");
    }
```

Comment: Nota: También cualquier sugerencia para la mejora del código es bienvenida:)

Comment: Pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que estás tratando de hacer exactamente con el código? Mejor dicho, si tuvieses que ir leyendo línea a línea por tu código, específicamente para describir tu algoritmo dentro de `if (pila.size() % 2 != 0)`, ¿cómo lo describirías? Hago esto porque si doy una respuesta directa de cómo hacerlo podrás presentarlo pero quizás no te ayude mucho a comprender la causa real del problema y eso te afectará mucho en el futuro (al menos si piensas seguir desarrollando luego de culminar tus estudios)

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ no se entiende mi codigo? :(

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ te explico: Primero recibes una expresion y verificas si su longitud es un numero par o impar

Comment: Sí lo entiendo. Mi pregunta es: ¿podrías explicármelo con tus propias palabras? Es muy probable que al tratar de explicarlo a otra persona puedas encontrar pistas que te lleven a ver el problema y cómo corregirlo. No lo digo yo, es el [método de depuración del patito de goma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Método_de_depuración_del_patito_de_goma)

Comment: Mira, creo que se volverá algo extenso hacerlo en comentarios. Crearé una sala de chat y allí podremos platicar mejor al respecto.

Comment: ok , esta bien.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65159/discussion-between-luiggi-mendoza-j-and-michelle).

Comment: Podrian aclarar si la pregunta quedo respondida y hay una solucion? si es asi @Michelle podrias agregar la solucion?

Comment: ah si, ya quedo la solucion:) @gbianchi

Comment: la agrego alrato, porque ahorita tengo que arreglar el otro código de pilas...@gbianchi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas, te propongo una alternativa que creo que se entiende mejor.

## Concepto

Fíjate en el patrón de tus soluciones correctas:

> a+b
>
> a+b+c+d
>
> a+b+c+...+z

Todas estas soluciones tienen en común que los elementos impares son una operación (+). Dado que lo guardas todo en una pila podríamos comprobar si es correcta o no la expresión, analizando que los elementos pares sean distintos de "+" y los impares sean iguales a "+".

## Código

```
public class Ejercicio5sep {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList pila = new LinkedList();
    boolean correcto = true; //suponemos que es correcto desde el principio

    System.out.println("Cuantos elementos quiere introducirle a la pila?");
    int n = x.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("introduzca su elemento");
        String e = x.next();
        pila.push(e);
    }
    //a partir de aquí cambiamos el código
    if(pila.size() % 2 != 0)  //Si el tamaño de la pila es par, la expresión es incorrecta
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < pila.size(); i++)
       {
          String a = pila.get(i).toString();
          //si es elemento par y no es "+"
          if(i % 2 == 0 && !a.equals("+"))         
          {
             continue; //continuamos con la siguiente iteración
          }
          else
          {
             if(i % 2 != 0 && a.equals("+")) //es impar e igual a "+"
             {
                 continue;
             }
             else
             {
                 correcto=false;
                 break; //salimos del for, no es necesario seguir
             }
          }
       }
    }
    else
    {
       correcto = false;
    }
   if(correcto)
   {
      System.out.println("La expresion es correta");
   }
   else
   {
      System.out.println("La expresion no es correta");
   }
  }
}
```

> Uso **pila.get(i)** en vez de **pila.pop()** porque entiendo que **pila.pop()** modificará el **tamaño de la pila** y por tanto, el valor retornado por **pila.size()**.

Esta forma de plantear el algoritmo te evita tener que analizar toda la expresión si es incorrecta, dado que en cuanto encuentra algo incorrecto, se deja de buscar.

Espero que te sirva y sea fácil de entender.