# expresiones aritméticas con pilas

Tags: java, poo, lista, pilas

**Ejercicio:** Leer una expresión aritmética agrupada por paréntesis y verificar si sintácticamente  esta bien formada.

Considerar:

1.Los paréntesis cierran y abren correctamente, existen pares de ellos.

2.Deberán usarse letras como literales (mayúsculas o minúsculas).

3.Revisar el uso adecuado de los operadores (que necesitan dos operandos).

4.Los paréntesis abren y cierran adecuadamente las expresiones:   (a + b) y no (a + ) b.

Ya escribí el código, y el único problema que tengo es que cuando le doy como `input: a+()` da como `output: La expresion esta escrita de manera correcta`, pero es incorrecta, como podría solucionar el problema **?**

Nota: El código compila bien.

```
public class Prueba {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("De que tamaño sera su expresion?");
    int n = x.nextInt();

    LinkedList pila = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pila2 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pila3 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pp = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList ppo = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pilaC = new LinkedList();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca su elemento");
        x.nextLine();
        String e = x.nextLine();
        pila.push(e);

        pila2.push(e);
        pila3.push(e);

    }

    int a = 0, b = 0;

    while (!pila.isEmpty()) {
        String element = (String) pila.pop();

        if ((0 == element.compareTo(")")||0 == element.compareTo("(")) 
  && !pila.isEmpty()) {
            String sim = (String) pila.pop();
            if (0 == sim.compareTo("+") || 0 == sim.compareTo("-") || 0 
 == sim.compareTo("*") || 0 == sim.compareTo("/")) {
                a++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (a != 0) {
        System.out.println("La expresion no esta escrita de manera"+ 
 "correcta");
    } else {

        while (!pila2.isEmpty()) {
            String simbolo = (String) pila2.pop();
            if ((0 == simbolo.compareTo("+") || 0 == 
  simbolo.compareTo("-") || 0 == simbolo.compareTo("*") || 0 == 
  simbolo.compareTo("/")) && !pila2.isEmpty()) {
                String el = (String) pila2.pop();
                if (0 == el.compareTo("(")||0 == el.compareTo(")") || 0 
  == el.compareTo("+") || 0 == el.compareTo("-") || 0 == 
  el.compareTo("*") || 0 == el.compareTo("/")) {
                    b++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (b != 0) {
            System.out.println("La expresion no esta escrita de manera" 
 + "correcta :/");
        } else {

            while (!pila3.isEmpty()) {
                String e = (String) pila3.pop();
                if (0 == e.compareTo("(") || 0 == e.compareTo(")")) {
                    pp.push(e);
                }
            }
            while (!pp.isEmpty()) {
                ppo.push(pp.pop());
            }

            int w=0;
            while(!ppo.isEmpty() && w!=1){
                String s=(String)ppo.pop();
                if(0==s.compareTo("(") && !pilaC.isEmpty())
                    pilaC.pop();
                else{
                    if(0==s.compareTo("(") && pilaC.isEmpty()){
                        System.out.println("La expresion no esta"+ 
  "escrita de manera correcta ");
                        w=1;
                    }
                    else
                        pilaC.push(s);


                }
            }
            if(w==1)
                System.out.println();
            else
            {
              if(!pilaC.isEmpty())
                  System.out.println("La expresion no esta escrita de"+ 
 "manera correcta ");
              else
                  System.out.println("La expresion esta escrita de"+ 
 "manera correcta :)");
            }




        }

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución del ejercicio utilizando solamente **pilas**:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solucion {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("De que tamaño sera su expresion?");
    int n = x.nextInt();

    LinkedList pila = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pila1 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pila2 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pila3 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pila4 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pila5 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pp = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList ppo = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pilaC = new LinkedList();

    x.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca su elemento");

        String e = x.nextLine();
        pila.push(e);
        pila1.push(e);
        pila2.push(e);
        pila3.push(e);
        pila4.push(e);
        pila5.push(e);

    }

    int a = 0, b = 0;

    if (pila1.size() == 1) {
        String u = (String) pila1.pop();
        if (0 == u.compareTo("+") || 0 == u.compareTo("-") || 0 == u.compareTo("*") || 0 == u.compareTo("/")
                || 0 == u.compareTo("(") || 0 == u.compareTo(")")) {
            System.out.println("Expresion incorrecta");
        }
    } else if (pila5.size() == 2) {
        String xx = (String) pila5.pop();
        String yy = (String) pila5.pop();
        if (0 == xx.compareTo("+") || 0 == xx.compareTo("-") || 0 == xx.compareTo("*") || 0 == xx.compareTo("/")
                || 0 == yy.compareTo("+") || 0 == yy.compareTo("-") || 0 == yy.compareTo("*") || 0 == yy.compareTo("/")) {
            System.out.println("La expresion es incorrecta.");
        }
    } else {

        while (!pila.isEmpty()) {
            String element = (String) pila.pop();

            if (0 == element.compareTo(")") && !pila.isEmpty()) {
                String sim = (String) pila.pop();
                if (0 == sim.compareTo("+") || 0 == sim.compareTo("-") || 0 == sim.compareTo("*") || 0 == sim.compareTo("/")) {
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (a != 0) {
            System.out.println("La expresion no esta escrita de manera  correcta");
        } else {

            while (!pila2.isEmpty()) {
                String simbolo = (String) pila2.pop();
                if ((0 == simbolo.compareTo("+") || 0 == simbolo.compareTo("-") || 0 == simbolo.compareTo("*") || 0 == simbolo.compareTo("/")) && !pila2.isEmpty()) {
                    String el = (String) pila2.pop();
                    if (0 == el.compareTo("(") || 0 == el.compareTo("+") || 0 == el.compareTo("-") || 0 == el.compareTo("*") || 0 == el.compareTo("/")) {
                        b++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (b != 0) {
                System.out.println("La expresion no esta escrita de manera correcta :/");
            } else { 
                String w = null;
                int c = 0, d = 0, k = 0;
                while (!pila4.isEmpty()) {
                    String v = (String) pila4.pop();
                    if (0 == v.compareTo("(") && !pila4.isEmpty()) {
                        w = (String) pila4.pop();
                        if (0 == w.compareTo("+") || 0 == w.compareTo("-") || 0 == w.compareTo("*") || 0 == w.compareTo("/") || 0 == w.compareTo("(")) {
                            c++;
                        } else {
                            k++; 
                        }
                    }

                }

                if (k != 0) {
                    System.out.println("La expresion no esta escrita de manera correcta.");
                } else {

                    while (!pila3.isEmpty()) {
                        String e = (String) pila3.pop();
                        if (0 == e.compareTo("(") || 0 == e.compareTo(")")) {
                            pp.push(e);
                        }
                    }
                    while (!pp.isEmpty()) {
                        ppo.push(pp.pop());
                    }

                    int ww = 0;
                    while (!ppo.isEmpty() && ww != 1) {
                        String s = (String) ppo.pop();
                        if (0 == s.compareTo("(") && !pilaC.isEmpty()) {
                            pilaC.pop();
                        } else if (0 == s.compareTo("(") && pilaC.isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println("La expresion no esta escrita de manera correcta :(");
                            ww = 1;
                        } else {
                            pilaC.push(s);
                        }
                    }
                    if (ww == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println();
                    } else if (!pilaC.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("La expresion no esta escrita de manera correcta :-(");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("La expresion esta escrita de manera correcta :)");
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Nota: Al igual que la respuesta de DanielGS, si `input: a+()`, `output:"La expresion es correcta"`. Y así debe de ser, porque lo que está diciendo es que a `a` sumale `"vacio" o () o 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Muy buenas, de igual modo que hice en mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100373/57433) a tu [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/100204/57433) relacionada con este tema, voy a tratar de mostrarte un código sencillo de entender y manejar.

## Comentarios previos

En primer lugar nos vamos a olvidar de todas esas pilas, sólo necesitamos una **lista**.
Por otra parte, para que sea más fácil de depurar, vamos a crear una función que nos permita simplificar los condicionales.

## Concepto

Lo que vamos a hacer es ir recorriendo nuestra lista y analizando los elementos a pares entre el **actual** y el **anterior**. 
Por ejemplo: si mi elemento actual es un **(**, el anterior tiene que ser un operador a la fuerza **+,-,/,***, en caso contrario, la expresión es incorrecta.

> Para no tener problemas en nuestro bucle, el primer caso lo analizaremos de forma independiente.

## Código

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prueba 
{
    public static boolean esOperador(String e)
    {
        return (e.equals("+") || e.equals("-") || e.equals("*") || e.equals("/"));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("De que tamaño sera su expresion?");
        int n = x.nextInt();
        int numParentesisAbiertos = 0;
        //Declarandolo con <String> 
        //te ahorras tener que hacer luego los casting
        LinkedList<String> lista = new LinkedList<String>(); 

        x.nextLine(); //esto debe ir fuera del bucle
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Introduzca su elemento");
            String e = x.nextLine();
            lista.add(e);
        }
        //hasta aquí hemos guardado en nuestra lista 
        //analizamos el primer caso fuera del bucle
        String primero = lista.get(0);
        if(esOperador(primero) || primero.equals(")"))
        {
            System.out.println("La expresión es incorrecta");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(primero.equals("("))
        {
            numParentesisAbiertos++;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < lista.size(); i++)
        {
            String previo = lista.get(i-1);
            String actual = lista.get(i);
            System.out.println(actual);
            switch(actual)
            {
                case "(":
                {
                    if(!esOperador(previo))
                    {
                        System.out.println("La expresión es incorrecta");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    numParentesisAbiertos++;
                    break;
                }
                case ")":
                {
                    if(numParentesisAbiertos == 0 || esOperador(previo))
                    {
                        System.out.println("La expresión es incorrecta " + numParentesisAbiertos);
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    numParentesisAbiertos--;
                    break;
                }
                case "+":
                case "-":
                case "/":
                case "*":
                {
                    if(esOperador(previo) || previo.equals("("))
                    {
                        System.out.println("La expresión es incorrecta");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default: //es una variable
                {
                    if(!esOperador(previo) && !previo.equals("("))
                    {
                        System.out.println("La expresión es incorrecta");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(numParentesisAbiertos==0)
        {
            System.out.println("La expresión es correcta");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("La expresión es incorrecta");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

## Notas del código

Fíjate en un par de cosas respecto al código:

1. En cuanto la expresión es incorrecta en algún apartado, el programa se detiene. Por tanto, sólo comprobará la expresión completa si es correcta o el elemento que da el error es el último. Esto hará más rápidas tus ejecuciones.
2. Fíjate en lo fácil que se lee un código bien tabulado, con sus `{}` puestas en todos los bloques. Te recomiendo que te intentes acostumbrar a seguir un buen estilo de código. **Yo uso llaves incluso para los condicionales con 1 sola línea.**
3. He realizado un par de cambios en la primera parte de tu código ya que no funcionaba correctamente. Por ejemplo el caso de `x.nextLine();` dentro del `for`.

## Ejemplo de entrada/salida

> **Input:** a+b*(c+d)-a
>   **Output:** La expresión es correcta

Espero que se comprenda y te sirva.

Comment: hmm pero se supone que `input: a+b*(c+d)-a` es incorrecto por la indicación 3, es decir, no puede pasar esto: `b*(` pues `(` debe de ser un operando

Comment: Si es es así, entonces sólo puede haber paréntesis al principio y al final, ya que justo después de una variable no puede ir y según comentas tampoco justo después de un operador. Creo que la indicación 3 no se refiere a los paréntesis por lo que te comento.

Comment: ah ya, si tienes razon. Entonces a que se refiere la indicación 3?

Comment: Se refiere a dos operandos. Por ejemplo: `a+b` tiene dos operandos: **a** y **b**. Pero en a+(b-c) , el **+** tiene dos operandos también: **a** y **(b-c)**. Es decir, todo lo que hay dentro de un paréntesis se puede entender como una única variable, de hecho, como primero se hace esa operación, cuando se vaya a realizar la operación **+** habrá 2 operandos: **a** y el resultado del paréntesis. Espero que se entienda, si te sirvió la respuesta indícalo para que los nuevos usuarios que lo vean lo sepan.